# JavaScript - object "this"

Tags: javascript, object

I have two JavaScript objects.

- Obj1 - static class
- Obj2 - instance

After adding item in Obj1 and running the method `isAdded()` from Obj2 there is a problem.

`obj1.func` stores a function, that holds the keyword `this` for Obj2. If I call `Obj1.func([args])` `this` is now for Obj1 instead of Obj2.

Any answer Please?

```js
var Obj1=function(){};
Obj1.func=null;
Obj1.addItem=function(vstup){
    //    code for add - AJAX async ....

    //    after adding
    Obj1.func(id, nazev);
};

//    ----------------------------

var Obj2=function(){
    this.variable=null;
    this.promenna2=null;

    this.isAdded=function(){
        this.variable="added";
        alert("ok");
    };
};

//    ---------------------
//    in body

window.onload=function(){
    var instanceObj2=new Obj2();
    obj1.func=instanceObj2.isAdded();
    obj1.addItem("test");
}
```

Comment: Obj1 - static class Obj2 - instance... **In English**

Comment: I'm completely lost here. Which line is giving you the problem?

Comment: The only `this` that i see is for OBJ2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `obj1.func = instanceObj2.isAdded()` which means: `set`**`obj1.func`**`to the result of`**`instanceObj2.isAdded()`**, which is: `obj1.func = undefined` since `obj2.isAdded()` returns nothing.

if you then execute `obj1.isAdded()`, which runs `Obj1.func`, you are essentially executing `undefined` as a function.

To fix it:

```
obj1.func = function() { instanceObj2.isAdded(); };
```

**Calling something within another context (aka: running something and setting "this")**

To run something with a different **this** value:

To set the context of a function, you can use either **[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** or **[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**

```
function add()
{
    var result = this;
    for(var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++)
        result += arguments[i];
    return result;
}
var value = 2;
newValue = add.apply(value, [3,4,5]); // = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5;
// newValue = 5
newValue = add.call(value, 3, 4, 5) // same as add.apply, except apply takes an array.
```

**Creating a new function, with a context**

In new browsers (ie9+) it's possible to use **[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** to create a callback with a set context (this) and set arguments which precede other arguments.

```
callback = func.bind(object);
callback = function() { func.apply(object, arguments); }

callback = func.bind(object, 1, 2);
callback = function() { func.apply(object, [1, 2]); };
```

Comment: +1, or on modern browsers (or with a polyfill): `obj1.func = instanceObj2.isAdded.bind(instanceObj2);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's why i love SO: always learning something new :-), i'll add it to my answer!

Comment: `obj1.func = instanceObj2.isAdded;` :)

Comment: @Shomz: No, `this` would get messed up, and `isAdded` *does* rely on `this`.

Comment: @Shomz if you run `obj1.func()` then, `this` would refer to `obj1` and not to `isntanceObj2`. That's the difference. If it were that easy, why would they introduce `Function.prototype.bind` ? ;-)

Comment: Right, just read the question in detail, didn't really pay much attention at how much it relies on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript this refers to currently being used element, So it's reference keep changing
Best method is to store (this) in a variable. and use it where you want that.

Like

```
var obj1This=this;
var obj2This=this;
```

And later use them

```
obj2This.isAdded();
```

Comment: Why do you keep the "this" terminology in variables for which it is inappropriate?